# How to Find Row Number DataTable

Tags: c#

I working on web application where i have to find a row position in dataTable . Please help me to figure this out . 
Here is windows application Code example

```
 pos = paesiBindingSource.Find("ISOCode", country);
```

what i am trying to do in my webApp is here

```
pos = Convert.ToInt32(PerfDBCountryTable.Select(country, "ISOCode").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct property that returns the index of a `DataRow` in the table.

But you can use [`DataRowCollection.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.indexof(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
DataRow[] rows = PerfDBCountryTable.Select("Country = " + country, "ISOCode");
if(rows.Length > 0)
{
    int index = PerfDBCountryTable.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0]);
}
```

Another approach is using `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
int firstMatchingRowIndex = PerfDBCountryTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
    .Where(x => x.row.Field<string>("Country") == country)
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .First();
```

Comment: I tried solution with linq which worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowNumber = 0; 
var pos = PerfDBCountryTable.Select(country, "ISOCode");

rowNumber = PerfDBCountryTable.Rows.IndexOf(pos);
```